# Matplotlib: Cycling through a list of hex colors does not work. Matplotlib still uses default colors

Tags: python, list, matplotlib, plot, colors

I am writing a class to quickly plot certain data which i have to deal with on a regular basis.I want to have the opportunity to pass a list of hex values to the method such that i can change colors if i want. But somehow my code (see below) is not working as it is not cycling through the list as expected via `color[i]` in the `for` loop.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator, FormatStrFormatter
import numpy as np
import os, sys
from pylab import *

COLORS=['#1f77b4' , '#ff7f0e' , '#2ca02c' , '#d62728' , '#9467bd' , '#8c564b' , '#e377c2' , '#7f7f7f' , '#bcbd22' , '#17becf']
color=COLORS

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6.29921,4),dpi=150)
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
Column_names=list(df.columns)
print (Column_names)
for (col,i) in zip(Column_names[1:],range(1,len(Column_names))): # for now "
    print(color[i])
    # Why does this below not work to cycle the color?
    ax.plot(df["A"],df[col],linewidth=0.8,label=col, marker='o',markersize=2.5,color=color[i])
ax.legend(loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.5),borderaxespad=0, frameon=False)

plt.show()
```

I guess it is not passing the quotation marks of the hex values?

EDIT:

I add a picture of my output:

[image: MY Output]

Comment: I fail to see the problem. The colors you get are exactly the ones you specify in the list. Could you maybe add an image of the undesired output and use it to explain what's wrong with it?

Comment: I have uploded a picture of my output. I would expect to get the colors i specified via "COLORS"  but instead i get the standard python colors. The list of colors i specified above are the hex values of tghe "tab10" colors btw.

Comment: But those colors *are* the ones you specify. *B*  is `'#ff7f0e'`, *C* is `#2ca02c`, *D* is `'#d62728'`.

Comment: But if `color=['#1f77b4' , '#ff7f0e' , '#2ca02c' , '#d62728' , '#9467bd' , '#8c564b' , '#e377c2' , '#7f7f7f' , '#bcbd22' , '#17becf']` as i have specified them untop of the script shouldn´t `color[i]` pick ` '#1f77b4'  '#ff7f0e' ....` ?

Comment: `i` starts at `1` in your loop.

Comment: i am so stupid! Thank you